# Running jar with dependencies from a batch file

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, jar, execute

I have generated a jar using Maven and now i want to execute it from a batch file from a different directory.
My jar has a few dependencies which are all dscribed in the pom file.[but are not in my jar]
I was wondering is there a way to execute the jar without causing ClassNotFoundException? 
if i run the jar with the dependencies in it everything runs fine, but isn't it a bit wasteful to package all the external JARs in mine?

Comment: possible dupplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: You can have the batch file set the classpath to include the dependencies.Note that (I think) if you do this, you can not use the `-jar` option with `java`. You'll have to set the main file explicitly.

Comment: i know how to package my classes with all the dependencies in a JAR i dont know if its possiblr to run a jar without its dependencies

Comment: You need the dependencies, but they do not have to be packaged into your jar.

Comment: @bradimus that's a way, thanks ;]

Answer (score 2):

Make the batch modify your classpath to add the needed jars to it.

[Apassembler maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/index.html) may help.